# using DateDiff to find duration in minutes

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, datediff

I am trying to use `Datediff` to find out the duration between `columnA` and `columnB`.

```
SELECT datediff (minute, stime, etime)
from Exceptions2
where stime = [exceptions2].starttime
and etime = [exceptions2].endtime
```

This produces errors. Can anyone please help me with what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: use the `WHERE` clause to filter results. It's not for creating aliases, unfortunately. :)

Comment: If Raymund's answer is what you were looking for, consider giving him credit by marking his as the accepted answer. It's not necessary to post another answer just to comment. :)

Answer (score 66, accepted):

how about trying this, not sure why you have stime = [exceptions2].starttime and etime = [exceptions2].endtime

```
SELECT datediff(minute, starttime, endtime) from Exceptions2
```

Comment: I could add that the result depends on the layout of starttime and endtime. If starttime is newer than endtime, the result is negative and the reverse is positive.